# apache2 -V getting error messages

Tags: command-line, server, apache2

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid
>
> Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}

My apache is located under /usr/sbin/, when I run `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V` as I follow some instruction to see what and where the config file is, I get this error message, along with some lines saying "config variable is not defined".

Mine is Ubuntu 16.04 and I install apache and stuff through virtualmin, does this have anything to do with the error message? And how do I get to see the config file's name with shell command(Yes it is right there in the error message, but I'd like to know the right command to see it, by "right" I mean without error messages).

Line 74 of that file is

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

Comment: That variable is defined on line 23 of `/etc/apache2/envvars`, you may check that. 
The value on my installation (unmodified) is `export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX`

Comment: Mine too. So...?

Comment: Ok, so i thought there was a typo on the config, or you miss the value. Then i tried the command myself and i got the same result. Then i read again the question, and  i searched for "get apache config file" ....so this is the answer (2nd result on google) `apache2ctl -V` from [second comment on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12202042/1810128) ....